# mySQL row number generation on statement already used join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, row, rows

```
SELECT b.commonname
FROM Bodymass m LEFT OUTER JOIN Bird b
ON m.eolid=b.eolid WHERE m.mass>2 AND m.mass<=3.3
GROUP BY b.commonname
```

Commonname
'Akepa
Acadian Flycatcher
African Stonechat
African Wagtail
Alaska Chickadee
Allen's Hummingbird

My current mySQL generates result without displaying row number as above. 
I have been searching for a hint for how to display row number as sample result below and only get below codes which is used for selecting from single table only.(No joining needed).
In my case, i already used *left outer join* once, how should I apply below for generating row number?
If below can not be applied to my case, can any one provide alternative solution?
Thanks

Row num Commonname

1   'Akepa

2   Acadian Flycatcher

3   African Stonechat

4   African Wagtail

5   Alaska Chickadee

6   Allen's Hummingbird

```
SELECT  c.course_id, 
         @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    course c
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
```

I tried alternated the code with applying the above row number generation code as following. There is error "You have error in your SQL syntax"

```
SELECT b.commonname, @curRow := @curRow+1 As row_number
from bodymass m left outer join b on m.eolid=b.eolid where m.mass>=2 
join (SELECT @curROW:=0) r
where m.mass>=2 and m.mass <=3.3 group by b.commonname;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT @currow:=@currow+1 as row_number, t1.commonname
FROM (
SELECT b.commonname AS commonname FROM Bodymass m LEFT JOIN Bird b
ON m.eolid=b.eolid 
WHERE m.mass>2 AND m.mass<=3.3
GROUP BY b.commonname ) t1, (SELECT @currow:=0) t2;
```

(you don't have to say LEFT OUTER JOIN, simply LEFT JOIN will do)

Answer (score 0):

You need for the `join` to be in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT b.commonname, @rn := @rn+1 As row_number
from bodymass m left outer join
     bird b
     on m.eolid = b.eolid cross join
     (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
where m.mass >= 2 and m.mass <= 3.3
group by b.commonname
order by b.commonname;
```

I also added the `order by`.  You seem to want the results in alphabetic order.  You should include an explicit `order by` when you want a specific order.

Comment: Another example of a seemingly malicious downvote on what seems like a correct answer.

Comment: | commonname                | row_number |

| Allen's Hummingbird       |          3 |
| Bee Hummingbird           |         10 |
| Black-chinned Hummingbird |          2 |
| Broad-tailed Hummingbird  |          6 |
| Calliope Hummingbird      |          5 |
| Costa's Hummingbird       |          4 |
| Flammulated Owl           |          7 |
| Ruby-throated Hummingbird |          1 |
| Rufous Hummingbird        |          8 |
+---------------------------+------------+

Comment: @user3459594  . . . I'm not sure what that comment is supposed to mean.  If you want to post code or a table, the best way is to edit your question.

Comment: apologize for the previous comment. The code is not generating what i expected. The result table is showing so random numbers which I am not sure what they represents for.

Comment: @user3459594 . . . That seems unlikely.  The code to add row numbers generally works.  Can you put an example up on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: why would you need cross join here?

Comment: @Ashalynd . . . It is the correct syntax for joining two tables/subqueries where there is no join condition.